# How to line break in StatusMsg in InnoSetup?

Tags: inno-setup, inno-setup-v6

```
Filename: "{app}\program.exe"; Parameters: -d; \
  StatusMsg: "How to put line break after this sentence? This sentence should be on new line."; \
  Flags: runascurrentuser;
```

I tried `+ #13#10 +` and `%n` but they didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status message line has one line only (so while you can insert a new line into the message, the second line won't show).

The second line is reserved for a file name (when files are being installed).

You can abuse the file name line like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\program.exe"; Parameters: "-d"; \
  StatusMsg: "How to put line break after this sentence?"; Flags: runascurrentuser; \
  BeforeInstall: SetFileName('This sentence should be on new line.'); \
  AfterInstall: SetFileName('')
```

```pascal
[Code]

procedure SetFileName(FileName: string);
begin
  WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Caption := FileName;
end;
```

[image]

---

Another (more complicated) option would be to temporarily make status line higher (multi-line).

Answer (score -1):

This code works:

```
Filename: "{app}\program.exe"; Parameters: -d; StatusMsg: "How to put line break after this sentence?%nThis sentence should be on new line."; Flags: runascurrentuser;
```

I added the **%n** as new line symbol.
But remember - your application *Program.exe* must support this symbol and recognize it the as new line (the symbol is passed from Inno Setup correctly).

Comment: `%n` works in (custom) messages only. And even is you use custom message in `StatusMsg`, the second line won't show. Also note that it's `StatusMsg`, not `Parameters`, so the value has nothing to do with `Program.exe`.